# Should instance variables used inside Kotlin suspending functions be Volatile?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Should instance variables used inside suspending functions be `@Volatile`, because under the hood multiple threads might access it?

Consider this example:

```kotlin
class VolatileDemo {

    private var blockedUserCount = 0 // Shouldn't this be @Volatile?

    suspend fun countBlockedUsers() {
        while (moreUsers()) {
            val user = getNextUserFromDb() // calls another suspending function
            if (user.isBlocked())
                blockedUserCount++ // may execute in a different thread, so have a stale value? 
        }
        println(blockedUserCount)
    }

    suspend fun getNextUserFromDb(): User { ... }
}
```

The `blockedUserCount++` inside the while loop is called after the `getNextUserFromDb()`, which is a suspending function. Doesn't it mean that `blockedUserCount++` might get executd in different thread each time? So, shouldn't it be declared as `@Volatile`, so that the value is correctly accessed by the threads that access it?

Comment: This question lack focus. Concurrent access is a broad subject. I advise you to read [*Shared mutable state and concurrency* section of Kotlin official documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/shared-mutable-state-and-concurrency.html). For a proper answer, you should at least provide one or two usage example of your `countBlockedUsers` function, so we can know what are the exact problem you're facing.

Comment: Thx, I edited my question to make it more explicit. Hope it makes sense now?

Comment: Your code seems very close to the section called [Volatiles are of no help](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/shared-mutable-state-and-concurrency.html#volatiles-are-of-no-help) from that document.

Comment: Nope, in my case there's no concurrent update to `blockedUserCount`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if everything is run on main thread, i.e. you don't have to worry about thread safety, `countBlockedUsers` shouldn't be called concurrently.

Referring to your comments ("in my case there's no concurrent update to `blockedUserCount`"), I'll assume no code in your program can call the method concurrently. This is not resilient to code changes, so I recommend you move this invariant into the class (e.g. slap a mutex on it).

---

Your main question is

> may execute in a different thread, so have a stale value?

The suspensions and resumptions of coroutines establish the "happens-before" guarantee. So the coroutine can be executed by multiple threads, and no stale values will be read in the coroutine.

---

This instance variable is probably read by another thread (otherwise you'd make it a local variable in the method). This is a data race.

As far as I understand the Java Memory Model, this is a benign race - nothing too bad will happen. But it's still a good idea to make the variable `@Volatile`.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, my main question is, whether we should make instance variables `@Volatile` in cases when it is accessed by different coroutines. You think we should. Corrcet?

Comment: Your question was one coroutine run by multiple threads - the answer is no volatile needed. For multiple coroutines, where exactly one of them writes, yes you need volatile - unless they are carefully confined in one single thread. For multiple coroutines run by multiple threads, where more than one of the coroutines read and write, "volatiles are of no help", as noted above by another comment in the question.

Comment: "one coroutine run by multiple threads - the answer is no volatile needed."
Thanks, that answers my question :) So, I understand that when the coroutine will wake up in another thread, it will be made sure that the value in that thread is up to date. Correct?

Comment: Yes the coroutine will see the writes it made in a previous activation, regardless if it was in a different thread, because of the "happens-before" relation. https://proandroiddev.com/what-is-concurrent-access-to-mutable-state-f386e5cb8292

Comment: That link uses a local mutable variable. My doubt was about an instance variable though. Nonetheless, because you mean it for instance variables as well, let me accept the answer and remove all `@Volatile` in my code for such cases. Thanks!

Comment: `m` is a local variable, but it's an object with state stored in its instance variables.